# Как получить locale browser(a) в java сервлете?

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Помогите получить Locale browser(a) в Java Servlet(e).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
 httpServletRequest.getLocale()
```

Информация о локали берется из http заголовка `accept-language`